# How to use call by reference(address) and default parameter in Java?

Tags: java

I am C++/C# developer and new to Java. Some reference found on internet suggests that we cannot have call by reference in Java. Is it completely true, or by any way I can return more than one value from function?

Secondly, default parameter is not seems to support in Java, I am also trying to find is there any way to use default arguments in Java.

Thanks.

Comment: 2 simple google search give the answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Some reference found on internet suggests that we cannot have call by reference in Java. Is it completely true

Yes. Java is pass-by-value, *always*. The values which are passed are either references or primitive values. (Objects are *never* passed, or returned. The value of a variable is always a reference or a primitive value. It's really important to understand this.)

> or by any way I can return more than one value from function?

You can create your own type composed of the various values. That's normally what I'd do. You *could* use an `AtomicReference<V>` parameter or an array as a *sort* of `ref` parameter... but I'd *strongly* encourage you not to. It would be very non-idiomatic.

> Secondly, default parameter is not seems to support in Java, I am also trying to find is there any way to use default arguments in Java.

No, there isn't. The closest approach is to overload the method, making an implementation with fewer parameters call an implementation with more parameters, specifying a default value as the "missing" arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have parse by reference in `Java` ,that's true.Java use pass-by-value

Second question you can use a `List` as return object if you want to `return` multiple values. Or create a custom class to `return`.

Comment: *You can't refer by reference in Java* - Lol! :D

Answer (score 0):

1. In Java references to Objects are passed by value. So, when you pass references, you are passing the location of the object. You can do whatever you want to "that" object in your called function. You can't have multiple return statements. But you can return multiple values  by putting them in some kind of container and returning the reference of the container.
2. No. (Some programmers consider using default arguments as a bad programming practice).

Answer (score 0):

For default argument type, you can achieve it by overloading. Example:

```
public first(String param1, int param2)
{
    this(param1, param2, false);
}

public first(String param1, int param2, boolean param3)
{
    //use all three parameters here
}
```